# Is it safe to run VACUUM and DELETE against a Delta Table while there's a Spark Streaming query doing data ingestion

Tags: databricks, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

I've got a 24/7 Spark Structured Streaming query (Kafka as a source) that appends data to a Delta Table.

Is it safe to periodically run `VACUUM` and `DELETE` against the same Delta Table from a different cluster while the first one is still processing incoming data ?

The table is partitioned on date and the DELETE will be done at partition level.

p.s. the infrastructure is on top of AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your streaming job is really append-only, then it should have any conflicts:

- `DELETE` on the partition level [can't conflict in WriteSerializable](https://docs.databricks.com/optimizations/isolation-level.html#write-conflicts-on-databricks) isolation level (default) if the write happens without reading (i.e. append-only workload)
- `VACUUM` simply removes files that aren't referenced in the latest version so it won't conflict with appends.